# Can I use an sharepoint client id+secret in PowerAutomate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I know you can change the credentials for a specific flow in Power Automate, but I have been looking for a way to use a client id+secret instead.

I found one example where you can request the token and use the SP rest API. but that one requires premium http connectors.

Any ideas how to just change the credentials to use client id+secret as a connection?

Or any workarounds that does not involves premium connectors?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Client ID and Client Secret is not supported by the SharePoint Online Connector. The only way to provide an authentication token to this connector is to enter user credentials in a pop-up window in a browser.

One workaround that **does require a premium license** would to be create a custom connector that uses Client ID and Client Secret to either communicate via Graph API or SharePoint REST API.